# What does this code mean (history.replaceState and history.pushstate)

Tags: javascript

i founded it, but I am not able to understand it

```
 history.replaceState( null, document.title, location.pathname + "#!/redirect" );
     history.pushState( null, document.title, location.pathname );
     window.addEventListener( "popstate", function() {
        if( location.hash === "#!/redirect" ) {
            setTimeout( function() {
                location.replace( "<<link>>" );
            }, 0 );
        }
    }, false);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

History.pushState()
Pushes the given data onto the session history stack with the specified title and, if provided, URL. The data is treated as opaque by the DOM; you may specify any JavaScript object that can be serialized.

History.replaceState()
Updates the most recent entry on the history stack to have the specified data, title, and, if provided, URL. The data is treated as opaque by the DOM; you may specify any JavaScript object that can be serialized.

for more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History
OR https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/